# Как правильно получить данные из таблицы?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
_userRepository.GetUsersWhereAsync(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == User.UserRoles.User));
```

Почему данный метод не работает?

```
 public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<User>> GetUsersWhereAsync(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter)
        {
            var users = await  context.Set<User>().Where(filter).ToListAsync();
            return await Task.FromResult(users.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Это бесполезная контрукция

```
 return await Task.FromResult(users.ToList());
```

Попробуйте так

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<User>> GetUsersWhereAsync(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter)
{
    var users = await  context.Set<User>().Where(filter).ToListAsync();
    return users;
}
```